# JDBC Hibernate Oracle extract database schema to compare changes

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

We have an Oracle 12c database in a live environment, the code used is from a branch of trunk. The application run with Spring 4.1.1 and Hibernate 4.3.6

Before merging changes from trunk to the live branch, we would like to have an automatic method to compare the 2 databases and check the differencies. This because we don't have a direct access to the live Oracle database and we need to provide the system administrator with SQL scripts to do the updates (client requirement).

Is there a way, from Hibernate or JDBC, to extract the live database schema?

If I'm not wrong, Hibernate schema export shouldn't be enough as it creates the schema from the hibernate annotation rather than using the database itself.

Some posts also suggest to invoke expdp (data pump) from command line through java, but we don't have access to the command line and we don't have the writing permission on the server anyway.

Is there a way to extract the schema using code only or is it an impossible task?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find any code solution to this problem. What we end up doing is to ask the client a schema export made with expdp and use a desktop compare tool to spot the difference between the 2 databases and generate the SQL needed.